# QBackingStore::endPaint() called with active painter on backingstore paint device

Tags: qt, qml, embedded-linux, yocto, beagleboneblack

I'm following [this tutorial](https://jumpnowtek.com/rpi/Qt5-and-QML-Development-with-the-Raspberry-Pi.html) for deploy qml to yocto. I'm using beaglebone black not raspberry but i think it is not important. When i ran cmd "./QmlProject" on beaglebone black , I had an error:

```
QBackingStore::endPaint() called with active painter on backingstore paint device
```

Does someone have a solution for this? or Does someone have a solution for deploy qml to yocto?.

Comment: what version of Qt do you use?

Comment: Hi  Oleksandr Kravchuk  , I  tested on QT5.10.1, 5.11.1 and 5.9.1

Comment: any updates on this please? same is happening with me when deploying to board with QT5.10.1

Comment: NOT JUST AN EMBEDDED LINUX problem, I am seeing it on a full RHEL box with QT 5.12.9

Answer (score 0):

I am getting this warning when i am trying render my pdf file on linux using poppler.

my QT version 5.11

I have a doc viewer class with paint event method. It's gets QPaintEvent e (QPaintDevice) and calling method RenderPages with painter and this device.
My code was:

**DocViewer.cpp**

```
void DocViewer::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e)
{
    qDebug()<<"cccc";
    QPainter* painter = new QPainter(this);

    m_IDocWidget->RenderPages(painter);
}
```

A possible solution is ending painter after render pages

```
void DocViewer::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e)
{
    qDebug()<<"cccc";
    m_painter->begin(this);

    m_IDocWidget->RenderPages(m_painter);
    m_painter->end();
}
```